# How to extend Python with C++?

Tags: python, c++, wrapper, swig

I have Python code which does the following:

1. Gets an optimization problem from simulation software.
2. Solves this optimization problem using multi-threaded IPOPT algorithm.
3. Converts the results obtained in 2 to another dimension.
4. Displays the result in the form of a figure.

Now I have written a class in C++ to solve the optimization problem (point 2) to increase speed and for some other reasons, which takes in output from point 1 (the problem, constraints etc.) and gives an output which is further passed into point 3 (a function in Python).

How to pass on these variables obtained from 1 to a C++ class in 2 and then back to Python function in 3? Following is what I am trying:

I used SWIG in order to generate wrapper file. The interface file for SWIG to create a wrapper for `2.cpp` and `2.h` C++ file:

```
/* File: 2.i */
%module t2c_main
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "../include/2.h"
%}
%include ../include/2.h
```

After running SWIG I got one Python file and one cxx file. Now I have problems in using these files; as mentioned above, I need to pass variables.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly you pass in the variables obviously depends on how you have your data stored. Let's assume though, that the t2c_main module contains a method addDataPoint(int,int);

What you would do then is the following:

- Compile and link the generated cpp file together with your 2.cpp into a dynamic library.
- If the generated python file is named t2c.py, rename the dynamic library you just compiled to _t2c.pyd  (note the underscore, that is actually important).
- import the t2c module in your python code

You should now be able to do something like

```
t2c.addDataPoint(5,10)
```

in your python code.

Comment: Thank you for your kind support and help.